# How long does it take for a loop to run in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm making a program that runs something for the amount of minutes the user alots (it's an idle game in beta). I put on a timer for one minute and noticed that the program ran over the minute by a couple of seconds-- Not very noticable, but I was wondering if this is because of how long a loop takes to execute? This is my code:

```
import time

foreverloop = True
automodeOn = False

idleSec = 0
idleMin = 0

pages = 0
pps = 0

while foreverloop:
    if automodeOn == False:
        msg = input("BTCG Command >> ")
        if msg == 'auto':
            autotime = input("How long would you like to go idle for? Answer in minutes.")
            automodeOn = True
        elif msg == 'autoMORE':
            pps += .5
    else:
        pages += pps
        print("You have auto-read",pps,"pages.")
        idleSec += 1
        if idleSec == 60:
            idleSec = 0
            idleMin += 1
        if idleMin == int(autotime):
            print("Idle mode turning off.")
            automodeOn = False
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What's slowest here (besides the `sleep` of course) is the content of your loop -- the `print`s and `input`s in particular. The actual loop itself is negligible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How long do they take to execute?

Comment: Depends completely on things we have no way of knowing from here.

Comment: What terminal software do you use? What's its latency? Where does it buffer, and how much? The right thing is to measure your actual system under a realistic workload if you need to collect numbers. Almost none of this is under Python's control, and none at all is common to all the varied hardware, operating systems, and surrounding environments where Python runs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using IDLE3 for Mac, but how do I check its latency and where it buffers? I'm sorta new to Python and programming in general :/

Comment: In general, if you need to care, you're doing something wrong. Design your software in such a way that it tolerates inexact timings (as by periodically syncing up with the wall clock, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the program wait in adittion to the time it takes to execute, I would use `time.time()` to get the system's current [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in seconds as a float and only continue if a certain time has passed:

```py
import time

time_begin = time.time()
wait_time = 60 # seconds to wait

while time.time() < time_begin + wait_time:
    # do logic
    print("Time passed:", time.time() - time_begin)
    time.sleep(1) # can be whatever

print(wait_time, "seconds has passed!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could measure the time it takes for a number of lines of code to execute by measuring the start time:

```
start = time.time()
```

before any number of lines you'd like to measure the time, then at the end adding:

```
end = time.time()
```

the time elapse is then calculated as their subtraction:

```
elapsed_time = end-start
```

I suggest that you read about code complexity, the most popular of which is the Big O notation.

edit: as denoted in a comment, `timeit` is the better option if you're looking to *precisely* measure the time it takes for a certain line or function to execute, the main difference between the 2 approaches is that `timeit` is made *specifically* for this purpose and as part of this takes as a parameter a variable `number` indicating the number of times the specified code is run before determining how long it takes **on average** to run.

Comment: However, there's a reason we often tell people to use `timeit` instead of just comparing instantaneous values -- the latter is often very noisy, and it's hard to know how meaningful values are without running the same thing thousands of times and looking at the level of consistency.